# PropertyChanged always null

Tags: silverlight-4.0

This is my MainPage.xaml :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightPlainWCF.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SilverlightPlainWCF.CustomersServiceRef" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customerViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:Customer, CreateList=True}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="426" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="customerDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="776">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" Header="Address" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cityColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=City}" Header="City" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="companyNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=CompanyName}" Header="Company Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contactNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ContactName}" Header="Contact Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contactTitleColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ContactTitle}" Header="Contact Title" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="countryColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Country}" Header="Country" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="customerIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerID}" Header="Customer ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="faxColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Fax}" Header="Fax" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Phone}" Header="Phone" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="postalCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PostalCode}" Header="Postal Code" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="regionColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Region}" Header="Region" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is my MainPage.xaml.cs :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using SilverlightPlainWCF.CustomersServiceRef;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SilverlightPlainWCF
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = Customers;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> customers;

        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return customers; }
            set
            {
                customers = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Customers"));
                }
            }
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            CustomersServiceClient objCustomersServiceClient = new CustomersServiceClient();

            objCustomersServiceClient.GetAllCustomersCompleted += (s, res) =>
            {

                if (res.Error == null)
                {
                    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(res.Result);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(res.Error.Message);
                }
            };

            objCustomersServiceClient.GetAllCustomersAsync();
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Do not load your data at design time.
            // if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            // {
            //  //Load your data here and assign the result to the CollectionViewSource.
            //  System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource myCollectionViewSource = (System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["Resource Key for CollectionViewSource"];
            //  myCollectionViewSource.Source = your data
            // }
            // Do not load your data at design time.
            // if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            // {
            //  //Load your data here and assign the result to the CollectionViewSource.
            //  System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource myCollectionViewSource = (System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["Resource Key for CollectionViewSource"];
            //  myCollectionViewSource.Source = your data
            // }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

If i just move the line :-

```
this.DataContext = Customers;
```

from constructor to here :-

```
if (res.Error == null)
                {
                    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(res.Result);
                    this.DataContext = Customers; 
                }
```

It works fine and I get all the data. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it didn't work when you put it in the constructor is that there is not yet any value in the `customers` field at that moment.

You will only get the value when `MainPage_Loaded` is triggered, which will not happen because of the following line in your XAML:

```
Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
```

That will execute `UserControl_Loaded` and not `MainPage_Loaded`. What you can do is call `MainPage_Loaded` from `UserControl_Loaded`, which probably is not what you intend to do. So in that case you should change your XAML instead to:

```
Loaded="MainPage_Loaded"
```

And you can delete `UserControl_Loaded` altogether since you are not using it anymore.

And as for the assigning of the result to the DataGrid, you can actually do it directly by assigning the result straight to the `DataContext` instead of going through the `Customers` property.

But if you insist to assign it to the `Customers` property and have the DataGrid updated accordingly, then the next easiest solution would be to include the following line somewhere in your `Customers` set method:

```
DataContext = value;
```

If you really, really insist that the DataGrid should update itself when the `PropertyChanged` event is triggered, without having you to code the `DataContext = Customers` row, then what you want is data binding. By binding the `DataContext` property to your `Customers` property, then the DataGrid will be updated when it receive the `PropertyChanged` event.

To declare the data binding in XAML, you would need to assign a name to your `UserControl` tag. Then you would assign the binding to the `DataContext`, something along this line:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=Customers, ElementName=theUserControlName}"
```

And if I were you, instead of having to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, I would instead use [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) instead. Converting your example to use Dependency Property, I would have:

```
public static DependencyProperty CustomersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Customers", typeof(ObservableCollection<Customer>), typeof(MainPage), null);

public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Customer>) GetValue(CustomersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomersProperty, value); }
}
```

Just that, the property change notification will be handled by the framework.

Comment: - I've used `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update the grid as soon as the content of `ObservableCollection` changes. I've resolved the error just by setting `this.DataContext = this` instead of `this.DataContext = Customers` and according changed DataGrid's binding to `{Binding Path=Customers}` instead of `{Binding}`.

Comment: @Nitesh: You don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update the grid when the content of `ObservableCollection` changes, that is done automatically by the `ObservableCollection` itself. You implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to let the grid knows that you assigned a totally new instance of `ObservableCollection`. And yes, you can also set `this.DataContext = this`, that's another way of doing it. It would be better if you understand why it works the way it works.

Comment: - Thanks for being so kind. Now my concepts are getting clearer. However there are few more doubts. I hope you don't mind answering them. 1) When we add new row from UI(data grid), will the row be added in code behind's `ObservableCollection`? 2) Should i make a `DependencyProperty` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Which is the best practise? Isn't `INotifyPropertyChanged` more effecient?

Comment: @Nitesh, answering your questions:
1) Sorry, I'm not really sure about that. But I am pretty sure that if you add a new row in the code behind's `ObservableCollection`, then the `DataGrid` will be updated accordingly.
2) I can't say which one is the best practise, but for WPF / Silverlight related stuff, Microsoft is implementing most of their properties as Dependency Properties and by doing that, it automatically provides change notifications, binding support etc. Does that say anything? :)

Comment: - Yes it said everything and i have voted and checked your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that in the constructor you do not have this line:

```
Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(res.Result);
```

before you attempt to set the DataContext to that value.